# I am getting segmentation fault and i dont know why

Tags: c, virtual-machine

I am writing a vm from a tutorial and I keep getting segmentation fault. gdb is not giving me any info accept for that it is in int main() but I see nothing wrong, of course I have a bad eye for things that are wrong so if one of you smart people can help me that would be great

vm.c (I fixed the indentation)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
typedef struct OBJECT_t {
  uint8_t type;
  union {
    uint8_t  u8;
    int8_t   i8;
    uint32_t u32;
    int32_t  i32;
    void *ptr;
  };
} OBJECT;

typedef struct STACK_t {
  int top;
  int size;
  OBJECT *stack;
} STACK;
typedef uint8_t* (*instruction)(uint8_t *, STACK *);
STACK stack_new(int size) {
  STACK s;
  s.top = 0;
  s.size = size;
  s.stack = (OBJECT *)malloc(sizeof(OBJECT) * size);
  return s;
}
int stack_push(STACK *s, OBJECT o){
  s->stack[s->top++] = o;
  return s->top;
}
OBJECT stack_pop(STACK *s){
        return s->stack[--(s->top)];
}
OBJECT stack_peek(STACK *s) {
  return s->stack[s->top - 1];
}
void usage(){
  printf("usage: vm <file>\n");
  exit(1);
}
uint8_t *load_file(char *filename) {
  FILE *f;
  int size;
  uint8_t *code = NULL;
  struct stat st;
  if((f = fopen(filename, "r"))) {
    fstat(fileno(f), &st);
    code = (uint8_t *)malloc(st.st_size);
    fread((void *)code, 1, st.st_size, f);
  }else {
    printf("ERROR: cannot open file %s\n", filename);
    usage();
  }
  return code;
}
uint8_t *op_nop(uint8_t *ip, STACK *s){
  return ip + 1;
}
uint8_t *op_push_char(uint8_t *ip, STACK *s){
  OBJECT o;
  o.type = 'c';
  o.u8   = *(ip + 1);
  stack_push(s, o);
  return ip + 2;
}
uint8_t *op_emit(uint8_t *ip, STACK *s){
  OBJECT o = stack_pop(s);
  putchar(o.u8);
  return ip + 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  uint8_t *code;
  uint8_t *ip;
  STACK data;
  instruction ops[256];
  if(argc != 2){
    usage();
  }
  for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
    ops[i] = op_nop;
  }
  ops['c'] = op_push_char;
  code = load_file(argv[1]);
  data = stack_new(1024);
  ip   = code;
  while(*ip != 'h'){
    ip = ops[*ip](ip, &data);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

my program
hello.sp

```
c
c!cdclcrcocwc coclclcecHeeeeeeeeeeeeeh
```

this is my gdb output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004014a6 in main ()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224511/discussion-on-question-by-koukah-i-am-getting-segmentation-fault-and-i-dont-know).

Comment: If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as your C compiler, compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. BTW, if on Linux, see [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Of course read also documentation of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 1):

after fixing the problems discussed in the comments to the question:

when compiling AND when linking, use the parameter: `-ggdb3`  Which will:

1. result in a much larger object files and much larger executable.
2. will have the maximum amount of information for the `gdb` debugger.

Among other things, `gdb` will then display the line numbers.

then use the `bt` command to display the back trace of the stack at the time of a crash, so you know exactly how the code got to the crash.